# How to use a String instead of an Interger with an IF statement in a C# Console program?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have been learning the basics of C# with a Console Application. I was wondering if anyone knew how to use an IF statement with a String instead of an integer. It's a bit annoying and I need it so I can compare a value the user has outputted to the console. This is because the Console.ReadLine(); only likes Strings and not Integers. Below is my code:

```
string num = Console.ReadLine();

if (num == 9)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ooh my number is 9");
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `if (num == "9")`  ?

Comment: Can't you do 'if (num.Equals("9"))'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always validate integer user input with TryParse

[`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation
>   succeeded.

```
string value = Console.ReadLine();

if(!int.TryParse(value, out var num))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You had one job!");
}
else if (num == 9)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ooh my number is 9");
}
```

Comment: Needed some work to fix errors but worked afterward. Thanks!